# CSS/HTML Gap Issue

Tags: php, html, css

Ok, so when I see my div on my site and whenever I load it up there is always a someone significantly noticeable gap between the text and space above the text. I dont know if somethings wrong with my CSS and I have no clue how to fix this...

Here is a screenshot and code -

[image]

Thank you :-)

```
#box2
{
overflow:auto;
border: 10px solid #a1a1a1;
padding: 95px; 40px; 
width: 180px;
height: 5px;
border-radius: 25px;
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:0;
}
```

HERE IS SOME HTML

```
<!---Bad Rats--->
<img src="" width="450" height="200" align="left"></img> 
<div id="box2">
<div id="reviewtext">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your html too or maybe even make a jsfiddle.

Comment: ok sure here is some

Comment: Looks like your padding 95px to the top and bottom of your div. That is probably the issue. Also, it might help if you post your markup (html) and any other applicable css.

Comment: `padding: 95px; 40px; ` has a syntax error. Look at the 95px

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is in the invalid CSS making `padding` from all sides `95px`:

```
padding: 95px; 40px;
```

Make it look something like:

```
 padding: 0 40px;
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55pxzsb1/)

Comment: But then they are like 5px tall XD I cant have that